# AutoMap.AssemblyOf maps entire namespace

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, mapping

I am a complete beginner with Fluent and I am running into an issue which is probably my own fault.

I have a namespace containing 3 classes. Entity, EntityVersion and Property. No inheritance involved between the classes.

I try to only map the Entity class but what happens is that all classes in the namespace are being mapped. What am I doing wrong here?

```
private static ISessionFactory CreateSessionFactory()
{
    return Fluently.Configure()

        .Database(
                MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2005
                .ConnectionString("Data Source=MSCHOPMAN\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=framework;Integrated Security=SSPI"))               
        .Mappings(m => 
        {
            m.AutoMappings.Add(
               AutoMap.AssemblyOf<Entity>()
               //.IgnoreBase<Entity>()
               .Where(t => t.Namespace == "Modules.Business.Entities")
            )
            .ExportTo("c:\\temp");
        }
        )

        .ExposeConfiguration(BuildSchema)
        .BuildSessionFactory();
}
```

And the Entity class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;

using Modules.Data;

namespace Modules.Business.Entities
{
    public class Entity
    {
        public virtual int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual int ParentId { get; set; }
        public virtual int TypeId { get; set; }
        //public virtual IList<EntityVersion> Versions { get; set; }

        public Entity()
        {
            //Versions = new List<EntityVersion>();
        }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

This line:

```
.Where(t => t.Namespace == "Modules.Business.Entities")
```

instructs FluentNHibernate to map all objects inside the `Modules.Business.Entities` namespace. If you want to map only a particular type you could try specifying its name:

```
.Where(t => t == typeof(Entity))
```

Comment: Hi Darin, thanks for your answer. Maybe I am missing the entire point of the Entity type being passed in the first line:

What does the AddAssembly<Entity> represent / is used for? :)

m.AutoMappings.Add(AutoMap.AssemblyOf<Entity>).Where(t => t.Namespace == "Modules.Business.Entities")                )

Comment: It means map all types that are defined in the assembly in which the Entity type is defined (hope it makes sense).

Comment: It doesn't mean map the Entity type.